# using struts2 + the rest and convention plugins, problems outputting JSON/XML results

Tags: json, rest, struts2

i am exploring the use of struts 2 with the convention + rest plugin. there's a struts2-rest-showcase application that shows how to use these plugins with struts 2. in the example applications, they always redirect to a HTML page. i wonder if it is possible to write JSON/XML through the Response object? does anyone have any simple code to show how this may be done?

for example, a user may create a new resource at /myapp/orders/new and then get a JSON message back: { "results" : "New order created successfully" }. the code below is the in OrdersController and where i would rather write JSON back (as it is, it goes back to a HTML page in /WEB-INF/content).

```
public HttpHeaders create() {
 ordersService.save(model);
 addActionMessage("New order created successfully");
 return new DefaultHttpHeaders("success").setLocationId(model.getId());
}
```

on the other hand, is this requirement a proper use of REST? when i'm doing GET, POST, PUT, DELETE commands, what's the expectations on the content i get back? am i not supposed to get anything back (including XML/JSON)?